# Hiding a button in jsp on closing a pop up window using js?

Tags: javascript, jsp

In my jsp on clicking a button, I am showing a pop up window with using javascript. The pop up contents are displayed using another 3rd party site. 
 The pop up is having a close button and on closing the pop up, I need to hide or not display the button in jsp. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're also using JQuery, you can just get the id/class of the button and add the following to the js function called by your button:

```
$("#yourID").hide();
$(".yourClass").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(selector).hide();`   to hide an element, and here is how you can close your popup on outside click:

Also, you can use pure javascript and:

```
document.getElementById('elementId').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Click outside of the element to hide:

```
$(document).click(function (event) {

    if (event.target.className != 'elementToOpen' &&
      $(event.target).parents().index($('#popupWrap')) == -1) {

        if ($('#popupWrap').is(':visible')) {
            $('#popupWrap').hide();

            // .hide() will give selected element css(display:'none')
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the closing code of the popup, in your popup window, try this:

`window.opener.document.getElementById('myButton').style.visibility="hidden";`

If you don't have control over the closing code of the opened window, [Someone](http://atashbahar.com/post/Detect-when-a-JavaScript-popup-window-gets-closed.aspx) comes up with a clever idea:

```
var win = window.open('http://www.google.com', 'google','width=800,height=600,status=0,toolbar=0');   
var timer = setInterval(function() {   
    if(win.closed) {  
        clearInterval(timer);  
        document.getElementById('myButton').style.visibility="hidden";
    }  
}, 1000);
```

**Update:** For Internet Explore when loading page from a different domain to the opened window, it will return null instead of a reference to the window if Protected mode is on. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujyB5/).